# Get access to Git-Revision in Ansible Playbook executed in Ansible Tower

Tags: git, ansible, ansible-tower

We are using ansible tower to deploy software. The template and inventories are sourced from a Project which is based on a git repository.

For debugging purposes it would be great to be able to access the checked out `revision` in our playbook, so that we can e.g. write it to a file which we create during the deployment to be aware of the currently deployed version.

Is there a way to do this?
So basically I would like to access the highlighted `Revision` in our playbook as ansible variable.

[image: Screenshot of Ansible Tower with highlighted revision]

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `- debug: var=vars` and `- debug: var=hostvars` goes a long way toward knowing what information is available to you; what have you already tried?

Comment: Thanks @mdaniel this brought me on the right track! 
https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution myself:

> **tower_project_revision**: The revision identifier for the source tree that this particular job uses (it is also the same as the job’s field scm_revision)

https://docs.ansible.com/ansible-tower/latest/html/userguide/job_templates.html

Thank for your help!